# Mui v5 - TreeView - On parent collapse, collapse all descendant

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tree, frontend, treeview

When I collapse a TreeItem, I want all it's descendants TreeItems (it's children, their children, etc.) that are expanded to also collapse. How can I do that? Visual flow:

1.Initial state:

```
TreeItem #1
```

2.TreeItem #1 Expanded:

```
TreeItem #1
  TreeItem #2
```

3.TreeItem #2 Expanded:

```
TreeItem #1
  TreeItem #2
    TreeItem #3
```

4.TreeItem #1 Collapsed:

```
TreeItem #1
```

5.TreeItem #1 Expanded for the second time - WANTED CASE:

```
TreeItem #1
  TreeItem #2
```

5.TreeItem #1 Expanded for the second time - WHAT ACTUALLY HAPPENS:

```
TreeItem #1
  TreeItem #2
    TreeItem #3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, you need to override the default behavior of the `TreeView` component. This isn't extremely difficult, but can be somewhat confusing because the documentation isn't great.

You will have to make the `expanded` property of the `TreeView` controlled. Basically, this means having a state control which nodes are expanded/collapsed.

There are multiple ways to interact with the node, there are `onClick` methods, such as the `onNodeSelect`, `onNodeToggle`, and etc., you will need a way of capturing when the user clicks-to-expand.

Once you have the above, you can just have a function modify the state like so:

```
import { TreeItem, TreeView } from "@mui/lab";

function TreeDiagram(): JSX.Element {
   const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
   

   /**
    * Method to remove or include a node to the array of expanded node
    */
   const handleExpandedToggle = (nodeId: string): void => {
      setExpanded((prevExpandedState: string[]): string[] => 
         prevExpandedState.includes(nodeId)
            ? prevExpandedState.filter((node: string) => node !== nodeId)
            : [nodeId, ...prevExpandedState]);
   };

   /**
    * Method to handle the click event of the TreeItem's
    */
   const handleTreeItemClick = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, nodeId: string): void => {
      handleExpandedToggle(nodeId);
   };

   return (
      <TreeView
         expanded={expanded}
      >
         {/* All the tree items */}
         <TreeItem
            onNodeFocus={handleTreeItemClick}
            nodeId={"tree_item_1"}
            label={ /* Whatever you'd like here */ }
         ></TreeItem>
      </TreeView>
   );
};
```